# Mobile Vision API to scan entire line

Tags: java, android

I found Mobile Vision API to extract blocks, lines and words.It reading the line with contiguous words.But, If a word separated with more space was not displaying in the same line instead treating as separate line.

I want to read receipt values to get total price.

For Example:

total 20

total with one space was displaying in the same line

total                                                 3000

But total with more space displaying in separate line not in the same row.

I have stuck here and working on to get entire line in one row,but was not getting.please, Help me to get out of this issue.

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEQPm.jpg)
get the total and value in the same line

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try posting what you have done so far, posting your code will help.

Comment: List<? extends Text> textComponents = mText.getComponents();
                                                                                                   for(Text currentText : textComponents) {                                                           
         
        }

Comment: Above will read contiguous words in a line,but if the word is separated by lots of space then its not displaying in the same line